# Group cannot be found

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, groups, spweb

I am getting error `Group cannot be found` when I use following code:

```
string group = GetGroupName("1");  
SPUser user = web.SiteGroups[group].Users.GetByID(SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.ID);
```

But strangely following code works fine:

```
string group = "Marketing";  
SPUser user = web.SiteGroups[group].Users.GetByID(SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.ID);
```

The method `GetGroupName` is a static method that returns a string "Marketing". I don't know why it is not working in case1 but works in case2. I have checked hundred of times that the string returned by function is "Marketing" without any space or any other extra character.

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: The only two possiblities are GetGroupName changes `web` or doesn't return "Marketing"

Comment: I think it has something to do with `SPFieldMultiLineText`. That method reads value of department name from a list and that field is "Enhanced Rich Text" multiline. That method returns `mlt.GetFieldValueAsText(item[ConfigurationsList.Value])` and even though it is string, for some reason it doesn't work.

Comment: Instead of using a separate method that returns group name, I put all the code in line and still it has same problem. I have checked 100 of times and department name is same, even used `.Trim().ToString()` but same problem. Changed multiline field to single line of text and but issue. Looks like there is a bug in SharePoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can add the method below to solve this issue.

```
static string GetRichTextValue(string value)
{
    if (null == value)
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(value.Length);
    foreach (char c in value)
    {
        if (char.IsLetterOrDigit(c) || char.IsPunctuation(c))
        {
            sb.Append(c);
        }
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Then get group name using the following line of code.

```
string group = GetRichTextValue(GetGroupName("1"));
```

Comment: Your method got me thinking what the problem was. There were extra characters having code 8203 were coming in the string. I removed those characters and viola problem is solved. More about 8203 here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973698/whats-html-character-code-8203